# Fetch result from MongoDB without deserialization

Tags: .net, mongodb

I need to fetch lots of data from Mongo, and feed it directly to the client Javascript without processing in the middle, so I don't actually need the data to be deserialized/re-serialized.

I understand that Mongo does not actually store data in JSON (it just looks like it), but is there a way to minimize the amount of time spent serializing/deserializing the data ? With a few hundred thousand objects by query, each one takes a surprisingly huge amount of time.

The most basic way I have found to get JSON is this :

```
return this.db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection")
            .Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("FileId", fileId))
            .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
            .ToList().ToJson(this.jsonWriterSettings);
```

Comment: Can you quantify "huge amount of time"? Are you specifically measuring the performance of only the ToJson() call?

Comment: "Huge amount" is between about 3 and 20 seconds, for between a few thousand and a few hundred thousand entries (after filter). The time has already been divided by 2 after adding an index on the FileId field. I haven't tried to measure the difference between the query itself and the deserialization, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve deserialization, but fetches a string directly from Mongo...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RawBsonDocument](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_RawBsonDocument.htm) (rather than BsonDocument), but I'm not sure that's going to completely solve your problem. You could try to tackle your own custom/specialized deserialization to improve efficiency.

Deserializing is generally a fairly expensive operation. If possible, minimizing the number of documents (perhaps by a schema change) and/or minimizing the number of fields should help.